# File open issues

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, file-io

What would be the reason that this code result in an `m_cause` of `0` for a file open. Found plenty of reasons that another code will be returned but no reasons for `0`.

```
CFileException fileException;
CFile myFile;
if (myFile.Open("C:\\test\\docs\\test.txt", CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite, &fileException))
{
    TRACE( "Can't open file %s, error = %u\n", "test.txt", fileException.m_cause );
}
```

Comment: You only enter this `if` block if condition evaluates to non-zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CFile::Open()` returns none zero upon success, the call in your example does not fail!

Check for  `!CFile::Open(...)`

Answer (score 0):

> ### Return value
>
> Nonzero if the open was successful; otherwise 0. The pError parameter is meaningful only if 0 is returned.

[Taken from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hwbccf8z%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (I've linked to the documentation for Visual Studio 2010, but it's the same going back as far as VS2005 and 2003, and probably beyond that).

As per bert-jan's suggestion, you should check for `!CFile::Open(...)` as in the event that the file does fail to open, you won't actually handle the error.